# Top down menu items gone

Tags: user-interface, menu, quick-settings

So this is a little stupid but I did something that caused all of my items in the top dropdown menu  to disappear and there is only a wifi icon left.

When I press edit it doesn't change anything, I have no idea what I did. I've never seen it do this before.

I'm asking here because pretty much anyone I ask is kind off baffled and doesn't know what is going on. Maybe it's a bug?

It somehow happened while pressing a notification

Info:
ZTE Axon 7
Android 7.1
MiFavor UI 4.2

[image: all items are gone, but appear when edit is pressed]

Comment: @beeshyams The cog is spinning but it appear to open the settings menu afterwards, can't find any UI tuner either.

Comment: I am able to go into UI tuner via Nova launcher widget and then searching for the system UI activity and dragging demo mode into the screen. But I don't see any options here that would help me.

Comment: @beeshyams To be honest, not even LineageOS has the Settings cog behaving that way.

Comment: Sorry can't help further. Huawei users would be better placed to help

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman: Thanks. Guess I am mixing up things// Florian -sorry for the trouble and misdirection

Comment: @beeshyams what do you mean with huaewei users, is that a part of this site?

Comment: No I meant users who are familiar with that brand and UI of Huawei devices - those users can probably help is what I meant